# Replace node text with Mule & groovy

Tags: groovy, mule

I am trying to replace the text value of a node using a groovy scripting transformer in Mule.

I first use a XML to DOM transformer then I am using the following

```
<scripting:transformer name="replacePassword">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[import org.dom4j.*
import groovy.xml.DOMBuilder
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory

Node passwordElement = message.payload.getRootElement().selectSingleNode("//*[local-name()=\'Password\']")
passwordElement.setTextContent("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
return message.payload
]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer>
```

But this seems to be throwing the following exception

> Root Exception stack trace: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement.setTextContent() is
>   applicable for argument types: (java.lan g.String) values:
>   [xxxxxxxxxxxxx]

I am not too familiar with groovy is my script correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just look at the documentation for [org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement](https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.0.1/org/dom4j/tree/DefaultElement.html)

there is no `setTextContent()` method... but there is a `setText()` method

Comment: btw, `node.text = 'xxx'` actually calls `node.setText('xxx')` in groovy,  so that's absolutely the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

Went with this in the end, this will get a node and replace the text value

```
 <scripting:transformer name="replacePassword">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
            node = message.payload.getRootElement().selectSingleNode('//*[local-name()=\'Password\'][1]');
            node.text = 'xxxxxxx';
            return message.payload;]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:transformer>
```